# How to get the width of a string in pixels?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython's HyperTreeList and I want to set the column width exactly equal to length of the largest string in it.

To accomplish that, I'd like to to convert a python string size into pixels.

For Example: If we have a string like

```
str = "python"
len(str) = 6
```

How could I convert the above string length/size into pixels?

Is there another way?

Comment: The size in pixels will depend on the font you're using to display the string and the graphics toolkit you're using to render the font.  You're going to have to give us more information before we can help you.

Comment: I am using wxPython HyperTreeList and i want to set the column width exactly equal to length of a column value. 

Actually, i want to adjust the column size equal to size of largest string value in a column.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to do [something](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/693968-wxpython-status-bar-adjust-length-string) [like](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#GetTextExtent) (see the [documentation of wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxdc.html#wxdcgettextextent) for more info)

```
f = window.GetFont()
dc = wx.WindowDC(window)
dc.SetFont(f)
width, height = dc.GetTextExtent("Text to measure")
```

Comment: use GetColumnFont to get correct font and GetTextExtent to get width

Answer (score 11):

It depends on how you are printing the text.

You may be interested by `PIL ImageDraw` which has a `textsize` method. See http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm

Update: This was answering the original question. It may looks a little off-topic after question updates.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. FYI, the original answer didn't say that it was for WxPython. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: +1 sorry, didn't see the orginal unedited question, you answer was meaningful then.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my solution, I'm just passing it on as I found it works and
most useful
as in a program environment it reduces to only 3 lines. Python3.9 mac OS

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as W1

FW=Tk() ; FW.withdraw() # a must but don't need a window
Text ='1234567890'

def LENGTH(Text) :
    W2 = W1.Font(family='Comicsans' , size = 20)
    length = W2.measure(Text)
    print(length)

LENGTH(Text)
```

Comment: This is not as I typed it and makes it less understandable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).