# Arranging that a wxpython window inherits its size sensibly from its contents

Tags: wxpython

I've written my first wxpython application and it works fine, but I ran into difficulties properly sizing the main window. The  panel contains a `wx.BoxSizer` that, in turn, contains a `wx.FlexGridSizer` that, in turn, contains 6 `wx.TextCtrl`s.

The tutorials I have read seemed to focus on setting sizes manually. What I would really like to do is to have the `TextCtrl`s work out what size they should be to contain 3 characters from a given font (say "WWW") and that, in turn, should automatically determine the size of the FlexGridSizer and the main window. I don't need to worry about resizing the layout (so maybe the Sizer isn't necessary?), I just want the sizes to be determined automatically and not by me putting magic constants into the program.

```
import wx
from names_as_vs import name_sum, name_mult

NAME_SIZE = 35

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(405,200))

        self.default_init_UI()
        self.init_UI()
        self.Show()

    def default_init_UI(self):
        """Do all the standard UI stuff"""
        file_menu = wx.Menu()
        menuAbout = file_menu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,"About\tCtrl-A")
        menuExit = file_menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"Quit\tCtrl-Q")

        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu_bar.Append(file_menu,"File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

    def init_UI(self):
        """Particular UI setup for this program"""

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(2,5,9,9)

        fixed_elts_args = {"size":(30,70)}
        plus = wx.StaticText(panel, label="+", **fixed_elts_args)
        times = wx.StaticText(panel, label=".",**fixed_elts_args)

        equals1 = wx.Button(panel, label="=", **fixed_elts_args)
        equals2 = wx.Button(panel, label="=", **fixed_elts_args)
        equals1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compute_sum)
        equals2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.compute_mult)

        font = wx.Font(48,wx.ROMAN,wx.NORMAL,wx.NORMAL)
        text_ctrl_args = {"size":(95,70)}
        self.summand1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, **text_ctrl_args)
        self.summand2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, **text_ctrl_args)
        self.scalar = wx.TextCtrl(panel, **text_ctrl_args)
        self.multiplicand = wx.TextCtrl(panel, **text_ctrl_args)
        self.sum_result = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style = wx.TE_READONLY, **text_ctrl_args)
        self.mult_result = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style = wx.TE_READONLY,     **text_ctrl_args)

        for ctrl in (plus,times,equals1,equals2,self.summand1,self.summand2,
                     self.scalar,self.multiplicand,self.sum_result,self.mult_result):
            ctrl.SetFont(font)

        fgs.AddMany([ 
            self.summand1,plus,self.summand2,equals1,self.sum_result,
            self.scalar,times,self.multiplicand,equals2,self.mult_result
            ])

        hbox.Add(fgs, proportion=1, flag= wx.ALL, border=15)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A GUI implementation of 815 as a vector space",     "About 815 as a vector space", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal() # Shows it
        dlg.Destroy() # finally destroy it when finished.

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)  # Close the frame.

    def compute_sum(self,e):
        """Computes the sum of the names in summand1 and summand2 and displays the result in self.sum_result"""
        n1 = self.summand1.GetValue()
        n2 = self.summand2.GetValue()
        self.sum_result.SetValue(name_sum(n1,n2))

    def compute_mult(self,e):
        """
        Computes the scalar multiple of the name in multiplicand by the scalar in scalar and displays the result in self.mult_result
        """
        n = self.multiplicand.GetValue()
        lamb = self.scalar.GetValue()
        self.mult_result.SetValue(name_mult(lamb,n))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two steps you need to implement to solve your problem.

The first step is to calculate how wide your string (you give "WWW" as an example) will be. Please take a look at [this SO question about computing string widhs in pixels using wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455255/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-string-in-pixels). Once you have the width and height, you can set your `wx.TextCtrl` sizes.

The second step is setting the `wx.Frame` size. I want to start be saying that in wxpython terminology any object that can appear on screen is called a window and what most users would call a window (i.e. the thing with the minimize/maximize/close buttons in MS Windows) is called a frame. It can get confusing, I know.

So you want to automatically set the size of your frame using the size of the contents. Easy! You want to use the `Fit()` method ([documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#Fit)). You could also use the `SetSizerAndFit()` method ([documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetSizerAndFit)) but this is just a convenience method that calls both `SetSizer()` and `Fit()` at the same time. The `Fit()` method takes a look at the size of the contents of an object and sizes that object accordingly. Unfortunately, it's not quite that simple in your particular code.

In your code you have a `MyForm` (a `wx.Frame` instance) that contains a `wx.Panel` which then contains your sizers and your `wx.TextCtrl`s. Unfortunately, this causes problems computing the `MyForm`'s size based on the contents so calling `Fit()` will just set it to a default size. The reason is that `wx.Frame`s compute their size based on their sizers (as assigned by `SetSizer()`) and current `MyForm` does not have a sizer, so it cannot calculate the size based on the contents of your `wx.Panel`. Luckily there are two solutions to this problem and they're both pretty easy.

**1. Remove `panel` and set everything as a child of the `MyForm` directly then call `SetSizerAndFit()`**

This would look something like this:

```
def init_UI(self):

    [...]

    #note that the parent is now "self" and not "panel"
    self.multiplicand = wx.TextCtrl(self, **text_ctrl_args)
    self.sum_result = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_READONLY, **text_ctrl_args)
    self.mult_result = wx.TextCtrl(self, style = wx.TE_READONLY,     **text_ctrl_args)

    [...]

    self.SetSizerAndFit(hbox)
```

**2. Place `panel` inside of another sizer and call `SetSizerAndFit()` on the `MyForm`**

Which would look something like this:

```
def init_UI(self):

    [...]

    panel.SetSizer(hbox)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.Horizontal)
    sizer.Add(panel)
    self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
```

Finally, I want to offer a quick explanation as to why tutorials tend to use those "magic numbers". UI Design is difficult and sometimes you need things to be pixel perfect. If you're developing an app to be used on different computers with different settings and screen resolutions and even different OSes, ensuring everything is displayed consistently requires explicitly setting things like fonts and sizes and not relying on system defaults. As you progress and start making more complex wxpython applications you'll run into problems where sometimes the size of an object isn't calculated properly and using the methods I've told you to use will still make your window too big/small. Just keep this in mind moving forward.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe for future applications, you may also want to be aware of the `FitInside()` method ([documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#FitInside)). It does the opposite of `Fit()` and sizes the children based on the parent (instead of the parent based on the children).

Comment: Thanks also for this; I appreciate knowing about both directions.