# Width of a string with zero-width and two-width characters, in Python 3 in a terminal (not in a GUI)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, curses

I would like to format strings to show them with `curses`.
For that, I would like to add spaces if the line is too short, and cut it and add continuation characters if it is too long.

My problem is to compute the real width of the string in my terminal. In my string, I can have characters that won't be shown and others that will be of length two (and printed as square). Consequently, the function `len` is not a right candidate.

To solve that, I tried to use `unicodedate.category` to filter characters:

```
removed_category = ('Mn', 'So')
string = ''.join(char for char in string \
    if unicodedata.category(char) not in removed_category)
```

But it does not work for all cases. For instance, 'Ｓ' is detected as a uppercase letter but in terminal its width is not one.
Moreover, it is slow and not very elegant.

I also tried `string.printable` to it removes also characters than can be shown in my terminal.

**EDIT (since the question is closed)**

Solutions based on `unicodedata.east_asian_width` do not work with zero-width characters. If we combine that with `unicodedata.category`, it seems to work:

```
def stringWidth(string):
    width = 0
    for c in string:
        # For zero-width characters
        if unicodedata.category(c)[0] in ('M', 'C'):
            continue
        w = unicodedata.east_asian_width(c)
        if w in ('N', 'Na', 'H', 'A'):
            width += 1
        else:
            width += 2

    return width
```

Depending on your text, you may need to add other categores for zero-width characters.

Comment: Yay, the joy of Unicode double-width characters. And combining marks. And zero-width characters.

Comment: I believe this is a very similar question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455255/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-string-in-pixels

Comment: @Olivier: that's a GUI context, not a terminal.

Comment: `unicodedata.east_asian_width()` can help but is not foolproof either. See the duplicates.

Comment: I will edit the title to insist on no GUI context to avoid confusion with other questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately `unicodedata.east_asian_width()` does not work for zero-width characters.

Comment: Other questions do not talk about zero-width characters.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is interesting, but does not mention curses.